How to use Scroll-snap with lenis locomotive scroll
https://codepen.io/rosinida/pen/BargMXG
check out this codepen link here scroll-snap is not working when  lenis scroll is used for locomotive scroll
pls Help
I tried everything so please help now   below is the code of above code pen link this is not my exact work my exact work is on react but problem i am facing is same i.e, scroll-snap disables on using lenis locomotive scroll
<body>
  <div class="firstele">
    <div class="img-bg"></div>
  </div>

  <section></section>
  <section class="color-bg"></section>
</body>

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: initial;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*------------Add scroll snapping-------------*/
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  /*https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/#aa-example-3-vertical-full-screen*/
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100 1000;
  font-stretch: 25% 151%;
}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

/*---Fixed Image-Background---*/
.firstele {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-bg {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629116625181-67de6ca4d6b9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/*---section 1---*/

/*---section 2---*/
.color-bg {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

import Lenis from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@studio-freight/lenis@0.1.12";

const lenis = new Lenis({
  lerp: 0.1,
  smooth: true,
  direction: "vertical"
});

function raf() {
  lenis.raf();
  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}

requestAnimationFrame(raf);

